# d3.json not returning data values from my php api

Tags: php, api, d3.js

I'm trying to load data from my php api onto d3.json so that I can visualise it as a line chart.

This is my code:

```
d3.json("api.php", function(error, data) {
    var k = [];
      data.forEach(function(d) {
          d.date = d.date;
          d.close = +d.close;
          k.push(d.date)
      })
});
```

when I run `console.log(k)` to see if it did load data. It prints nothing.

This is a sample of my api.php:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"1",
      "exchange_symbol":"TSE",
      "currency":"JPY",
      "stock_id":"1",
      "stock_name":"KYOKUYO CO.,LTD.",
      "stock_symbol":"1301.T",
      "date":"2006-12-29",
      "time":"15:00:00.000000",
      "close":"2388.023438000000000000",
      "volume":"23700.000000000000000000",
      "active":"1",
      "exchange_id":"0"
   }   ...
]
```

What have I done wrong? Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Have you checked `error` variable too? It may tell you what's wrong.

Comment: what does `...` indicate in the JSON example?

Comment: hundreds of lines of continued data

Comment: i have tried a version of the code without error and returns the same result

Comment: Where did you place your `console.log(k)`?  It was within the `d3.json` callback right?

Comment: yea within the callback

Comment: Are you using d3.v5? or an earlier version of the library? You may need to check that you are using the correct callback syntax, since they have changed.

Comment: I am using d3 v4...

Comment: Ok, well then perhaps you can add a snippet of the failing data+code to the original post? Otherwise, we can mostly guessing...